# Count the number of males and females in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

Suppose I have this csv file named sample.csv:

```
CODE     AGE     SEX     CITY
----     ---     ---     ----
E101      25      M      New York
E102      42      F      New York
E103      31      M      Chicago
E104      67      F      Chicago
```

I wish to count the number of males and females in the data.  For instance, for this one, the answer would be:

```
M : 2
F : 2
```

Where should I start and how should I code it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")

print(f"M : {len(df[df['SEX'] == 'M'])}")
print(f"F : {len(df[df['SEX'] == 'F'])}")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import csv
>>> M,F = 0,0
>>> with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
...     data = csv.reader(csvfile)
...     for row in data:
...         M += 1 if row[2] == "M" else F += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Import the CSV file.
2. section out the 'SEX' column.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

num_males = sum(data['SEX'] == 'M')
num_females = len(data['SEX']) - num_males
```

Comment: There is no need to multiply by `1`, python will treat `True`s as `1` and `False`s as `0` when using in arithemtic, so `sum([True,True,True])` and `True+True+True` will both result in `3`.

Comment: ohh ok. Its a habbit now I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is using the pandas packages to do so.

```
import pandas as pd

csv_path_file = '' # your csv path file
separator = ';'

df = pd.read_csv(csv_path_file, sep = separator)
df['SEX'].value_counts()
```

will return a pd.Series object with 'M' and 'F' as index and count as values.
It is also a great workaround for checking wrong data, you'll immediately notice it if you have another category, or missing data.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to read data from csv and group by:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv') // read data from csv
result = df.groupby('sex').size() // use .size() to get the row counts
```

Output:

```
sex
f    2
m    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

After you read from file using either external `pandas` or built-in `csv` module, you might builtin module `collections`' `Counter` to count occurences, consider example:

```
import collections
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'CODE':['E101','E102','E103','E104'],'SEX':['M','F','M','F']})
for key, value in collections.Counter(df['SEX']).items():
    print(key,":",value)
```

Output:

```
M : 2
F : 2
```

Note I hardcoded data for simplicity. Explanation: `collections.Counter` is `dict`-like object, which accept iterable during creation and count occurences in said iterable.